# How to call an operator as function in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, function, operators

I want to call a specific operator of specific base class of some class. For simple functions it's easy: I just write `SpecificBaseClass::function( args );`. How should I implement the same for operators without casting trickery?

Isolated problem:

```
 class A
 {
 public:
     A operator+( const A &other ) const {...}
 };

 class B : public A
 {
 public:
     B operator+( const B & other ) const {...}

 };

 ...
  B a, b;
  B c = A::operator+( a, b ); //how this should be implemented? I get an error
 ...
```

I'm getting the following error from **GCC4.5.1**:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘A::operator+(B&, B&)’
note: candidate is: A A::operator+(const A&) const
```

*Thanks*!

---

**EDIT**
I've improved the example to better illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The operator is a nonstatic member function, so you could use

```
a.A::operator+( b )
```

However, for another class that defines `operator+` as a static member function, what you tried would be correct. And a third class might make it a free function (arguably the best way), so `B::operator+(a,b)` and `a.operator+(b)` would both be incorrect and `operator+(a,b)` would be right.

Generally it's best just to use operator syntax `a+b` unless you know exactly what class it is, and that its implementation will never change. In a template context, writing `a+b` is a must, and it's essentially impossible to take the address of the overload (the only task that *requires* naming it) without a lot of work.

In your context (a comment to another answer mentions templates), the best solution is

```
c = static_cast< A const & >( a ) + static_cast< A const & >( b );
```

… the problem is solved by slicing the types to reflect the subproblem, not precisely naming the function you want.

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
a.operator+(b);
```

Comment: In the specific case I have I should write  " static_cast<BlahBlahClass< TemplateParam1, TemplateParam2>*>(&a)->operator+(b) " which is not very readable

Answer (score 4):

The syntax of specifying a function as

```
<Class>::<Method>
```

is used when `Method()` is a static method in `Class`. If `Method()` is a instance method, then the invocation is on a class object.

```
Class classObject;
classObject.Method()
```

In this particular case, the declaration and usage of the `operator+()` method does not match.

So, one approach would be to make the `operator+()` method `static`. But, I think, `operator` methods can only be non-static member function or non-member function.

With all these knowledge, here is a full illustrative program.

```
#include <cassert>

struct B {
    int num_;

    B(int num) : num_( num ) {
    }

    static B add( const B & b1, const B & b2 ) {
        return B( b1.num_ + b2.num_ );
    }

    B operator+( const B & rhs ) {
        return B( num_ + rhs.num_ );
    }
};

int main() {
    B a(2), b(3);

    B c = B::add( a, b );
    assert( c.num_ == 5 );

    B d = a + b;
    assert( d.num_ == 5 );
}
```

The `add()` function is for example only, don't do it though.

Answer (score 4):

There are two notions in C++: one is operator, and the other is operator-function. Operator informally is what is broadly called a built-in operator. You cannot call them in functional notation. Operator-function is what is called an overloaded operator which you can call as already is seen from many answers: that is, if @ is a member binary operator of class A, then `someObjectOfTypeA.operarot@(someOtherObject)`, or if it is a freestanding function, then like `operator@ (object1, object2)`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just say

```
c = b + a;
```

Comment: You are assuming the + operator is symmetric for the class A. Though a good coding guide would suggest this it is not a requirement of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
B c = a + b;
```

Comment: Because he wants to use `A`'s implementation of `operator+`, but this will use `B`'s implementation of `operator+`.