# Why calling the "<<" operator as a function causes "ambiguous call" compiler error?

Tags: c++

Why the first code snippet works fine, but the second causes an ambiguous call error ? Why cannot the compiler resolve the function overload in the second case ?

Snippet 1:

```
int main() {
    int x = 1234;
    std::cout << x;
}
```

Snippet 2:

```
int main() {
    int x = 1234;
    operator<<(std::cout, x);
}
```

The compiler error when compiling the snippet 2:

```
more than one instance of "operator<<" matches the argument list

std::operator <<': ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is no global (or non-member) [`operator<<` overloaded function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for integers. It's [a member of the output stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt):

```
std::cout.operator<<(x);
```

A good compiler should have shown you the possible alternatives for an ambiguous call, which should have told you this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why the compiler knew that I mean `std::cout.operator<<` in the first snippet but not in the second one?.. Is there any reference to how c++ operators are resolved ?

Comment: @KeyBored Because that how operator overloading works with in-member overloading of operators. If the object on the left-hand side of `<<` have a member function `operator<<` then that will be called if it have an argument matching the right-hand side. Generically, `object x something` gets translated to `object.operatorx(something)` if there's a matching overload.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to call a member function (of `std::cout`) as if it were a free function: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt

The ambiguity probably comes from multple matches that all involve some sort of conversions, none of which is preferable. The compiler error probably gives you some horrendous impossible-to-read list of possible matches, all of which seem irrelevant?

---

For operators, call them as operators, not as functions! There are good reasons to define operators as members, and good reasons to define them as free functions. You shouldn't need to care which is used in any particular case.

If I want to create my own type that supports `+`, I may have good technical reasons to choose one approach over the other, and even change my mind in a future version of the library. Should you care which I choose?

---

Note that `operator<<` is a member function for built-in types (i.e. the various flavours of `int`s), but is a non-member function for other types, for example [`char const*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) or [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt).

Comment: That's exactly my point! You don't (shouldn't) know or care when it is a member function and when it is a free function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what I didn't get is why the compiler was able determine that `<<` is a member function of one of the operands in the first snippet, but couldn't do that in the second snippet ?!! .. given that we didn't specify any object in the first snippet (the working one) .. P.S.: I'm calling operators as functions just for learning purposes :)

Answer (score 1):

The operator is a nonstatic member function, so you could use
from : [how to call an operator as function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971124/how-to-call-an-operator-as-function-in-c)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x = 1234;
    std::cout.operator<<(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2):

```
template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,
                                        char ch );

template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,
                                        signed char ch );
```

The call will be ambiguous if overload resolution cannot select a match to the call that is uniquely better than such undifferentiable functions. For `x`(int), both `char` version and `signed char` version are fit, so it will be ambiguous. One more example:

```
#include <iostream>
void foo(char a)
{

}
void foo(signed char b)
{

}
int main() {
    foo(1);
}
```

> prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
>   prog.cc:11:10: error: call of overloaded 'foo(int)' is ambiguous
>        foo(1);

---

> But this code works fine operator<<(std::cout, "hello");

Because

`template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& const char* s );`

is the only choice for `operator<<(std::cout, "hello");`. One more example:

```
const char* z = "char*";  // OK 
const signed char* x = "signed char*";  // invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘const signed char*’ 
const unsigned char y = "unsigned char*"; // invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘unsigned char’
```